# How to set page layout of list item in SharePoint REST?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

How to change the page layout of list item using rest?

The below code was used in the process and the code gets executed, but the page layout doesn't change. Please advise.

```
itemProperties['PublishingPageLayout'] = {
            'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue',
               __metadata: { type: 'SP.FieldUrlValue' },
                Description: 'Custom Content Layout',
                Url: '/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomPage.aspx'
            };
function updateDocLibItem(url, itemType, itemProperties, etagId) {
    itemProperties["__metadata"] = { "type": itemType };
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": etagId
        },
       });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported to update `PublishingPageLayout` field value via SharePoint REST API since the field is marked as `ReadOnly`

**Workaround**

JSOM API could be utilized instead to update page layout as demonstrated below:

```
var itemIdToUpdate = 3;

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var listPages = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Pages");
var pageItem = listPages.getItemById(itemIdToUpdate);

var val = new SP.FieldUrlValue();
val.set_url("/_catalogs/masterpage/ArticleLeft.aspx");
val.set_description("Blank Web Part page");
pageItem.set_item("PublishingPageLayout",val);
pageItem.update();

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function() {
      console.log("Updated");       
  },
  function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

*With JSOM/CSOM APIs it is possible to update fields marked with ReadOnly attribute.*